# Why some binaries are duplicated in the Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, yocto

Good Morning,

There are some commands that are both in **/bin** and in **/usr/bin** in our Yocto filesystem.
Is that normal? I don't think it's a mistake we made in building our Yocto filesystem because I see the same thing in my regular Debian Buster distribution (see below). But what is the purpose of that duplication?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
root@debian:~# ls -l /bin/zip* /usr/bin/zip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 213136 Aug 16  2015 /bin/zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  90432 Aug 16  2015 /bin/zipcloak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48497 Jul 21  2020 /bin/zipdetails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2953 Jan 10 16:12 /bin/zipgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 183136 Jan 10 16:12 /bin/zipinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86048 Aug 16  2015 /bin/zipnote
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86048 Aug 16  2015 /bin/zipsplit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 213136 Aug 16  2015 /usr/bin/zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  90432 Aug 16  2015 /usr/bin/zipcloak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48497 Jul 21  2020 /usr/bin/zipdetails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2953 Jan 10 16:12 /usr/bin/zipgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 183136 Jan 10 16:12 /usr/bin/zipinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86048 Aug 16  2015 /usr/bin/zipnote
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86048 Aug 16  2015 /usr/bin/zipsplit
```

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Often /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin, could that explain what you're seeing?

Comment: In this case, these are two "real" directories. But maybe because I didn't build the filesystem the right way and got duplication? I need to take a closer look at how my filesystem is built.. :-)
4 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 19  2021 /bin
12 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         12288 Apr  9 15:20 /usr/bin

Comment: Something went wrong on your setup. Look at _zipinfo_ it is the  **same** file (literally, you have two pointers to it), but the rest is different indeed. Ah, Debian, they still doesn’t know how to package programs...

Answer (score 0):

some of those binary does some special functions and purpose other than the main program.

just take a look at the grep program

original 'grep'

extended ones are - egrep, bgrep, pgrep, fgrep.

they all do the same thing but gives the user more flexibility and ease of usage